# Removing added custom cell renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have created a custom cell renderer to fill a cell by a particular color.

```
public class ColorInCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer

    {
        private final Map<Point, Color> cellColors = new HashMap<Point, Color>();
        public void setCellColor(int row, int column, Color color)
        {
            if (color == null)
            {
                cellColors.remove(new Point(row, column));
            }
            else
            {
                cellColors.put(new Point(row, column), color);
            }
        }

        private Color getCellColor(int row, int column)
        {
            Color color = cellColors.get(new Point(row, column));
            return color;
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            Color color = getCellColor(row, column);
            c.setBackground(color);
            return c;
        }
    }
```

i used it in adding a row into jTable as follows.

```
private void addTableRow(String type, String name, String rank, String notes, String location, Color color)
    {
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]
        {
            type,
            name,
            rank,
            notes,
            location
        });
        colorInCellRenderer.setCellColor(tableModel.getRowCount() - 1, INDEX_OF_THE_COLOR_COLUMN, color);
        JTable.repaint();
    }
```

It works properly and fill the cell correctly. But when I remove the row it does not remove the filled color cell. Instead of it the color column replaces with the color cell in the next row. I tried by repainting the jTable after removing a row. But it does not work.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> But when I remove the row it does not remove the filled color cell.

Because you store the cells to be painted in your "cellColors" `Map`.

When you remove a row from the table you also need to remove the Point from the Map.

You can add a `TableModelListener` to the TableModel. You will be notified when a row is removed and then you can also remove the Point from the Map.